# How to place 5 ships randomly in a list of 20 positions for battleship game?

Tags: java, list, random

I need to put 5 ships randomly (numbers 1 to 5 witout repetition) in a list of 20 positions. I need to place a 0 where no ships are placed.
[e.g](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tifKR.png)
Please, I'm stuck here!

```
for (int i = 0; i < barcosComputadora.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0) {
                barcosComputadora[i] = rnd.nextInt(6);

            }
        }
    

    static void imprimirArreglo(int[] pValores) {
        for (int i = 0; i < pValores.length; i++) {
            out.print(pValores[i] + "\t");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int tam = 20;

        // tam = rnd.nextInt(20);
        int barcosComputadora[] = new int[tam];
        inicializarBarcosComputadora(barcosComputadora);
        out.println("\nValores del arreglo: ");
        imprimirArreglo(barcosComputadora);
    }


I got something like this:

0       0       5       2       2       0       2       2       5       2       1       0       0       4       5       3       0       0       3       4
```

Comment: What I could do is think about it backwards, that is, you have 20 places in which five ships can be placed.  I'd place all the positions in a `List` of some kind, randomise it and then just pop the first five.  This is overly simplistic and makes a number of assumptions, but might be a starting point

Comment: you can use collections.shuffle

Answer (score 0):

As MadProgrammer has mentioned. You can use a list of numbers to store the position.

```
List<Integer> = list of 0 to 19 to indicate position.
```

Then in that list, loop 5 times.
Every loop, pick a random number between 0 to **the size of the list** (the size of the list decreases every loop).
Use this random number as index to pick from the list.
Then remove the list at the index you obtained earlier. The list will auto compact itself i.e. the subsequent elements are shifted to the left by one place

For example you might pick list.get(3) of which the value is 3 also in the beginning. Then you remove/delete this index from the list. The next random number may be 4, so you pick list.get(4) of which the value is 5. And so on.